# Which method is getting executed when they have the same implementation of the same interface?

Tags: java

There is an interface with a method called

`foo(boolean arg1, String arg2);`

Additionally I have two classes which implement this method. Now when I call the foo method from the interface, how does it decide which implementation to pick?

The 2 implementations take the same parameters and return the same object but differ in the implementation.

Comment: The one which would be "more" concrete.

Comment: Perhaps you could show an example and indicate the behavior you're observing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you call

```
a.foo(b, c);
```

it looks at the type of the object `a` points to, not the type of the reference and calls the method that type implements.

Initially, it uses a virtual lookup table, which as you can image is expensive, so in the Oracle/OpenJDK JVM, it can inline up to two virtual methods dynamically based on usage so it looks more like this.

```
if (a instanceof Type1) {
    ((Type1) a).foo(b, c);
} else (a instanceof Type2) {
    ((Type2) a).foo(b, c);
} else {
    a.foo(b, c); // do a full vtable lookup.
}
```

Comment: thank you. I think I explained my problem poorly. In my example I have an interface which calls the method: interfaceX.foo(); There are multiple implementations of foo().

Comment: @M4V3N do you mean the method is overloaded? ie. there is multiple possible methods it could call for the same class?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot call methods on an interface... You need to call them on an object (an instance of a class implementing your interface). and that is the code that is called.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you asking about using interface methods in othere (default) interface methods.

Method will be chosen based on **instance** referenced by interface variable. Here is small example

```java
class Scratch {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ClassA varClassA = new ClassA();
        ClassB varClassB = new ClassB();
        Bar interfaceVar = varClassA;
        interfaceVar.foo("firstCall");
        interfaceVar = varClassB;
        interfaceVar.foo("secondCall");
        varClassA.foo("call from A");
        varClassB.foo("call from B");
        interfaceVar = new Bar() { // or just interfaceVar = System.out::println
            @Override
            public void printParam(String params) {
                System.out.printf("Anonimus class: %s%n", params);
            }
        };
        interfaceVar.foo("Anonimus call");
    }

    public interface Bar {
        default void foo(String param) {
            printParam(param);
        }

        void printParam(String params);
    }

    public static class ClassA implements Bar {
        @Override
        public void printParam(String params) {
            System.out.println(String.format(
                    "Called from %s wth params: %s",
                    this.getClass().getName(),
                    params)
            );
        }
    }

    public static class ClassB implements Bar {
        @Override
        public void printParam(String params) {
            System.out.printf("param from ClassB:%s%n", params);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Called from Scratch$ClassA wth params: firstCall
param from ClassB:secondCall
Called from Scratch$ClassA wth params: call from A
param from ClassB:call from B
Anonimus class: Anonimus call

Process finished with exit code 0
```